# How can i delete a contact from a list with the mailjet api and php?

Tags: api, mailjet

I use mailjet api to send newsletter, but i don't know how delete a contact from a list.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a developer evangelist here at Mailjet.

The relation between a `contactlist` and a `contact` is represented through the `listrecipient` entity. You can learn more about this in our guide, [here](http://dev.mailjet.com/guides/contact-list-guide/):

To remove a contact from a list, you have two options: either `DELETE` this entity or unsubscribe the contact from the list. The second solution has the advantage to keep the contact's status in the list. It prevents to send unwanted emails to a contact, if for some reason you add it in the list again later.

First, do a `GET` request to retrieve the `ID` of the `listrecipient` entity. 
As described in our reference documentation, [here](http://dev.mailjet.com/email-api/v3/listrecipient/), use the Contact and ContactsList filter. 
Once you have the `ID`, you can either run a `DELETE` request on it to permanently delete the contact in the list or set the `IsUnsubscribed` property to `true` to unsubscribe it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i have another problem i can't get the ID of the listrecipient, there is my code: 
function getContact() {
    $mj = new Mailjet();
 //$mj->listrecipient;
     $params = array(
        "method"    => "GET",
        "ContactALT"    => 'xxxxxxxx@gmail.com',
        "ListID"    => '1',
    );  
    $mj->listrecipient($params);   

    echo   $mj->_response->Data[0]->ID;
}

 the result is the ID of the listreciptient of the first contact. 
Thank's again. –

Comment: I found the solution
To get the ID of the listrecipient entity i use this function:
function getContact() {
    $mj = new Mailjet();
     $params = array(
        "method"    => "GET", 
  "ContactsList" => 1,
  "ContactEmail" => 'xxxxxxxx@gmail.com',
    );  
    $mj->listrecipient($params);   
   return   $mj->_response->Data[0]->ID; 
}
and to delete the contact from the list:

function deleteContact($ID){
 $mj = new Mailjet();
    $params = array(
        "method" => "DELETE",
  "ID" => $ID,
    );
    $result = $mj->listrecipient($params);  
}

deleteContact(getContact());

Thank you arnaud

Comment: Very welcome, glad you managed to make it work. Best.